# Java: how to count non-repeated (occurring only once) Strings in ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, unique, non-repetitive

I am trying to find the number of Strings that only appear exactly once in an `ArrayList`.

How many I achieve this (preferably with the best possible time complexity)?

Below is my method:

```
  public static int countNonRepeats(WordStream words) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String i : words) {
      list.add(i);
    }

    Collections.sort(list);

    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i - 1))) {
        list.remove(list.get(i));
        list.remove(list.get(i - 1));
      }
    }

    System.out.println(list);

    return list.size();
  }
```

Why doesn't it remove the String at `list.get(i)` and `list.get(i-1)`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner do you have any ideas? :)

Comment: you would get concurrent modification exception for the above method.

Comment: @RahulSharma Not quite, concurrent modification exception is thrown from Iterator which is created mostly via for-each, not simple `for(i..)`. But we may risk getting error because of wrong indexes.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't. But I tried to run the code and it works like a charm. @Iona do you get any errors?

Comment: If you use `Collections.sort` the time complexity is `O(n log n)`, but you can easily find the number of strings that appear exactly once in `O(n)` time using `HashSet`s (but no sorting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one simple suggestion:

1. First, sort your array by alphanumerical order
2. Iterate through with a loop, `if( !list.get(i).equals(list.get(i+1)) ) → unique`
3. If you find duplicates, increment `i` until you reach a different string

This will have the complexity of the sorting algorithm, since step 2+3 should be O(n)

Comment: that won't work because e.g. [apple, apple, banana, banana] will return 1 instead of 0 because apple != banana

Comment: No because that's what step 3 avoids! read more carefully. In this example, `"apple"` is a duplicate at `i = 0`, so you iterate until `!list.get(i).equals("apple")` → `i = 2` in the next cycle

Comment: ok you are correct! thank you sir! :) I'll upvote in 10 seconds

Comment: @Iona *How many I achieve this (preferably with the best possible time complexity)* Actually you don't even have to iterate it again. If you are using a `HashSet` then you can do it while scanning the words itself.

Comment: No need of sorting , please see my answer for better time complexity.

Comment: @SumitRathi you're not sorting, but you're calling `contains` (which iterates through a loop internally) in every cycle, which is exactly what you're avoiding by sorting. Your algorithm has `O(n*n)`...

Comment: @Malijam, since it will be a set of String, hash code of each String ideally, would be different, which in turn would result in a different hash, which in turn would result in putting each string in a different index of the array of  linked list(internal data structure used by HashMap). So Time complexity would **not** be o(n*n)

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for sorting.
A better approach would be to use two HashSet One for maintaining repeating and one for non-repeating words. Since HashSet internally uses HashMap, Ideally contains, get, put operation  has o(1) complexity. So the overall complexity of this approach would be o(n).

```
    public static int countNonRepeats(List<String> words) {

    Set<String> nonRepeating = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> repeating = new HashSet<String>();


    for (String i : words) {
        if(!repeating.contains(i)) {
            if(nonRepeating.contains(i)){
                repeating.add(i);
                nonRepeating.remove(i);
            }else {
                nonRepeating.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(nonRepeating.size());

    return nonRepeating.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any specific need of using an `ArrayList`? You can do it easily by using a `HashSet`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String[] words = {"foo","bar","foo","fo","of","bar","of","ba","of","ab"};
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> common = new HashSet<>();
    for (String i : words) {
        if(!set.add(i)) {
            common.add(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(set.size() - common.size());
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

Here is the modified code:

```
public static int countNonRepeats(WordStream words) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> common = new HashSet<>();
    for (String i : words) {
        if(!set.add(i)) {
            common.add(i);
        }
    }

    return (set.size() - common.size());
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! You can make it slightly more efficient by doing `if (!set.add(i)) common.add(i);`

Comment: @PaulBoddington Gotcha! :) Thanks for the valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hashmap to achieve this.With this approach we can count the occurrence of all the words,
 If we are interested in only unique words then access the element having count = 1. 
**`HashMap<String,Integer>`** - key represents the String from arraylist and Integer represents the count of occurrence.

```
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            String key = list.get(i);

            if (hashMap.get(key) != null) {
                int value = hashMap.get(key);
                value++;
                hashMap.put(key, value);
            } else {
                    hashMap.put(key, 1);
            }

        }
        int uniqueCount = 0;
        Iterator it = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            if ((int) pair.getValue() == 1)
                uniqueCount++;
        }
        System.out.println(uniqueCount);
```